Unable to Resolve Dependencies from EntityRepository in TypeOrmModule. But EntityRepository doesn't exists
I am working on a NestJS project that uses TypeORM. Currently implementing a data feed in the 'command handler' pattern so each user has a customized output from the same endpoint.
Error Message
 - [ERROR] - Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the XEntityRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument DataSource at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.

- Is TypeOrmModule a valid NestJS module?
- If DataSource is a provider, is it part of the current TypeOrmModule?
- If DataSource is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TypeOrmModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing DataSource */ ]
  })

Code Snippets
DummyFeedModule
import { Logger, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import DummyFeedService from './dummyfeed.service';
import { DummyEntity } from 'src/dummydata/infrastructure/persistence/relational/entities/dummy.entity';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([DummyEntity])],
  providers: [DummyFeedService, Logger],
  exports: [DummyFeedService],
})
export default class DummyFeedModule {}

DummyFeedService
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BaseFeed } from '../../base/feed.base';
import { DummyEntity } from 'src/dummydata/infrastructure/persistence/relational/entities/dummy.entity';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export default class DummyFeedService extends BaseFeed {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(DummyEntity)
    private repository: Repository<DummyEntity>,
  ) {
    super(
      'x',
      'x',
      'x',
      new Date('01-22-2024UTC'),
      new Date('01-22-2024UTC'),
    );
  }

  async execute(): Promise<DummyEntity[]> {
    return this.repository.find();
  }
}

FeedHandlerModule
import { Module, forwardRef, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { FeedHandlerService } from './feedhandler.service';
import { FeedEntity } from '../infrastructure/persistence/relational/entities/feed.entity';
import { RelationalFeedPersistenceModule } from '../infrastructure/persistence/relational/relational-persistence.module';
import DummyFeedModule from './feeds/dummy/dummyfeed.module';
import { DummyEntity } from 'src/dummydata/infrastructure/persistence/relational/entities/dummy.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([FeedEntity, DummyEntity]),
    RelationalFeedPersistenceModule,
    DummyFeedModule
  ],
  providers: [FeedHandlerService, Logger],
  exports: [FeedHandlerService, RelationalFeedPersistenceModule],
})
export class FeedHandlerModule {}

What I Have Tried

Verified that TypeOrmModule is correctly imported and used.
Confirmed that DummyEntity is correctly registered in the TypeOrmModule.
This DummyEntityRepository doesn't even exists, I don't know from where it comes.

Potential Issue
I suspect the issue might be related to how the import does modules.
Any guidance on how to resolve the dependency issue for DummyEntityRepository would be greatly appreciated.
